# Entity Framework simple names causes issue for some projects but not others

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure-webjobs

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with about 20 projects in it. Each of the projects references 2 class libraries that use Entity Framework 6. In these class libraries we have similar named objects that reside in differing namespaces. After adding a new Azure Web Job project I now get the exception below (just for the Web Job project):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The type 'AAA.BBB.Entity' and the type 'AAA.BBB.Entities.Entity' both have the same simple name of 'Entity' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.

Several other projects work and don't throw this exception - a REST API, Websockets API, Test Project, and std web app. I've compared project references, properties, packages, etc and can't figure out what the difference is. The only difference I can see is that the Web Job is a console application and the others are web apps and a test project.

Comment: I have the same issue in a Windows Service. Interestingly enough, I don't get this issue in a C# console app and in any of the website type projects. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known limitation of EF - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483. Unfortunately, due to how EF6 is architected it would be extremely difficult to fix. Note that if only one of the clashing classes is used in the model, then you should be fine if you are using Code First – but it will fail if you have an EDMX model. Trying to use both types in the same model will always fail, regardless of whether you are using code first or EDMX.

Comment: Thanks Rowan. I am only using one of the classes in the model (AAA.BBB.Entities.Entity). The other (AAA.BBB.Entity) is a public wrapper class with no ties to EF. What I can't figure out is why a call to one of the methods in all of my web apps and Test project works and the same exact call in the Web Jobs (console app) throws the exception.

Comment: As I dug further I realized that the AAA.BBB library was refactored using a base class from which both Entity classes are derived. The base class has the EF attributes which is why the exception is thrown. Still don't know why it's not thrown on the other project types, though.